# Accesing all subelements in a multidimensional array in javascript a la "mathematica"

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, wolfram-mathematica

In mathematica exists an special accessor for all the elements in an array which is very useful if you want from all the elements a subelement, this accessor is the word "All". It works like this:

```
data={{a1,a2,a3},{b1,b2,b3},{c1,c2,c3}}

data[[All,2]]
```

which gives:

```
{a2,b2,c2}
```

My question is: Does it exists something like that in javascript arrays, something like the accessor "All"?

If it doesn't exists, What is the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such operator, but here's a simple non-generic way to do it.

```
var data = [['a1','a2','a3'],['b1','b2','b3'],['c1','c2','c3']];

var extracted = data.map(function (arr) { return arr[1]; }); //["a2", "b2", "c2"]
```

Comment: Thank you! It's almost as easy as "All"!